# Promise-like Axios request in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, es6-promise

I  want make an Axios request in a promise-style way. The Axios-request is done in 'dataLayer.js'.
The problem is my 'dataPromise' is already fullfilled.
How do I have to extend 'createChargingStations()' in data Layer class to make a Promise-like call so I can handle the data in SFC with '.then()' as shown below?

Thx a lot!

```js
// dataLayer.js
export class modelFactory {  
    chargingStationsArray = []

    createChargingStations() {
        const requestPromise = axios.request(/* some request config */)
        const dataPromise = requestPromise.then(response => {
            response.data.forEach(dataEntry => {
                let cs = new chargingStation()
                /* some data mapping and transformation here */
                /* ... */
                
                // after tranformation, finally push chargingStation object
                this.chargingStationsArray.push(cs)
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("Promise Rejected: " + error);
        })
    }
}

// SFC.vue
<template> <!-- some template --> </template>

<script>
export default {
    /* name, components, data() etc. */
    methods: {
        updateMapOnFilterChange() {
            var mf = new modelFactory()
            const promise = mf.createChargingStations()
            
            promise.then(chargingStationsArray => {
                /* inject array into Vue component property */
            }).catch(error => {
               console.log("Promise Rejected: " + error);
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

EDIT: Published the long version of the code here https://jsfiddle.net/3azdnc4j/
You may get a better grasp what the code is supposed to do. But in my opinion it is not necessary for the basic problem!

Comment: cant tell what youve already changed. You can just chain promises, and dont forget to return it in the function. Its a tough concept sometimes.

Comment: Your code shouldn't be working as it is, `promise.then()` should throw. Please create an [mcve] like codesanbox

Comment: Not sure, what you wanna achieve, Do you wanna access `chargingStationsArray` data inside your vue file?

Comment: @Naren: Yes I want to access the full chargingStationsArray in the vue component then the request is done

Comment: @ TJ: I tried so, but had problems with babel transpilation and the correct vue version. So I decided to present my problem in an abstract and isolated manner, because it is more a conceptional problem I have.

Comment: What is a conceptional problem here? In the example the class doesn't serve a good purpose here. The instance isn't reused. And it won't be reused correctly because `chargingStationsArray` isn't cleaned  up between updateMapOnFilterChange calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export `ModelFactory` from `dataLayer` service, return the `axios` promise with  `map`ped response inside `createChargingStations`.

```
// dataLayer.js
class ModelFactory {  

    createChargingStations() {
        return axios.request(/* some request config */).then(response => {
            const chargingStationsArray = response.data.map(dataEntry => {
                let cs = new chargingStation()
                /* some data mapping and transformation here */
                /* ... */
                
                // after tranformation, finally push chargingStation object
                return cs
            })
            return chargingStationsArray
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("Promise Rejected: " + error);
            throw new Error('some error')
        })
    }
}

export default new ModelFactory()
```

and import in the vue file.

```
// SFC.vue
<template> <!-- some template --> </template>

<script>
import modelFactoryInstance from 'path-to-file/dataLayer'

export default {
    /* name, components, data() etc. */
    methods: {
        updateMapOnFilterChange() {
            modelFactoryInstance.createChargingStations().then(chargingStationsArray => {
            console.log(chargingStationsArray)
                /* inject array into Vue component property */
            }).catch(error => {
               console.log("Promise Rejected: " + error);
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code will fail at `const promise = mf.createChargingStations()` because `createChargingStations` doesn't return a promise.

The error should be handled at the point where a promise is consumed, handling it inside `createChargingStations` will make it resolve with `undefined`.

`promise` doesn't resolve with `chargingStationsArray`.

It should be:

```
createChargingStations() {
    const requestPromise = axios.request(/* some request config */)
    const dataPromise = requestPromise.then(response => {
        ...
    });
    return dataPromise;
}
```

and

```
updateMapOnFilterChange() {
    var mf = new modelFactory()
    const promise = mf.createChargingStations()
    
    promise.then(() => {
        mf.chargingStationsArray.forEach(...)
    }).catch(error => {
       console.log("Promise Rejected: " + error);
    })
}
```

Both `createChargingStations` and `updateMapOnFilterChange` can be rewritten with `async..await` in simplified manner.

Comment: Well it should be an isolated data layer. So I do not want to have run the data transformation in the Vue component

Comment: What kind of data transformation? You can do `await mf.createChargingStations(); this.chargingStationsArray = mf.chargingStationsArray`. Where chargingStationsArray is processed to the point it needs no transforms to be consumed.

Comment: No they say do not use async/await. If you do not have a full grasp of promises. The code just produces some model objects, but how can I consume these objects in the Vue component that way I have shown in the code

Comment: I agree about promises. Here async/await is a direct counterpart to raw promises, you are free to use the one you want. Once `mf.chargingStationsArray` is filled, it can be consumed in the component by assigning it to `this`. The question doesn't give a good idea what exactly the problem is. As for code issues, they are explained in the answer. The question was how to use data with `then`, that's how, it won't work correctly without specified fixes.